# I still remember the first time i listened to this song

Tags: sentence-construction

I feel like this sentence is grammaticaly incorrect when saying it but I can't find the mistake, or I feel that i could put "at" at the end. So, what is the right thing? Is it the original sentence, or is there is really a mistake, or can i put an "at" at the end?

Comment: You could feasibly introduce ***at*** using *the first time **at which** I listened to this song,* but it's unnecessary, and in your *exact* context it's not really idiomatic. Contexts where *the time at which* would be more reasonable *Do you remember **the time at which** you woke up this morning?*, but even there we'd nearly always use ***when*** (and might or might not explicitly include *the **time***). My advice: forget about ***at*** in contexts where you're talking about an ***occasion*** rather than the (clock-based) ***time** [of day]*.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake. The word "I" is always capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct.

> I still remember the first time I listened to this song at.

Would not be correct. You could feasibly say:

> I still remember the first time at which I listened to this song.

But it is not really idiomatic in this context. You sentence is fine as it stands. You don't need to use *at* when you are talking about an occasion rather than a clock based time.

Comment: I know, but it just felt wierd for me saying it, so I wanted to make sure. Thanks. And I didn't know about the I rule, my phone always capitalize it and I have to get back to write it like that. So, thanks again for letting me know that, and teaching me a new thing.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatical, but I think you're getting confused between two different meanings of *time*.

The basic meaning is "time on a clock", and *at* is the appropriate preposition for that meaning.

But in sentences like this, it has a different meaning, "occasion", and we would not use *at* with it. If it stands as a prepositional phrase, it uses *for* ("I have just listened to it for the first time"); but in this construction, it doesn't need a preposition at all.

[If you meant "time of day", you would have to make that explicit: "I still remember what time it was when I first listened to this song"].